# WCF Access is denied Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, exception

An attempt to run WCF Service results in the following below. I have tried the netsh related suggestions on the page referenced 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx
and have not gotten anything to work. Please help with information on how I can resolve this please.

Thanks in advance.

```
{"HTTP could not register URL http://+:8439/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details)."}

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at TestThreadSync.Form1.ListenOnChannel() in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\TestService\Form1.cs:line 51
   at TestThreadSync.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\TestService\Form1.cs:line 32
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at TestThreadSync.Program.Main() in C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\TestService\Program.cs:line 18
```

Answer (score 8):

Two options (either of two can be used)

1.Use netsh utility to provide access to the port

[netsh http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) add urlacl url=http://+:8439/ user=DOMAIN\UserName

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/01/29/addressaccessdeniedexception-cause-and-solution.aspx

2.Admin privileges are required

Run as Administrator (either Visual studio, or the application itself)

Comment: I tried the first already. the attempt was a success but did not solve the problem. However, when I tried to follow with the second, I now get a different exception message ***{"A registration already exists for URI 'http://127.0.0.1:8439/'."}***

Comment: use [netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:8439 ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307231(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I already deleted it, but the exception *** A Registration already exists for URI** persists

Comment: execute "netsh http show urlacl" and check if there is already any entry for 8439

Comment: Just checked and there does not seem to be a previous registration for this port number